# Subtract two dates in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

I want to subtract 2 dates in MS SQL Server.

Example:

```
Current date      Last used date
'2016-03-30'      '2015-02-03'
```

Current date refers to today's date, "Last used date" is a measure.

How to write a query in SQL Server?

I have this but doesn't work (it says "Operand data type is invalid for subtract operator")

```
select 
    CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) - CONVERT(DATE, LastUsedDate) 
from 
    databasename
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT     DATEDIFF(day,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05')     AS DiffDate
```

Output  DiffDate     61

More practice please refer below W3 school:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Comment: Please mark as answer if this one help to get your results! Thanks 

Answer (score 3):

Here you don't have to cast GETDATE() to date, as it is already datetime datatype. So your query will be as follows

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,CAST(LastUsedDate as date),GETDATE()) AS DifferneceDays
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal function to use is `datediff()`:

```
select datediff(day, cast('2016-02-03' as date), cast('2016-03-30' as date))
```

You can subtract `datetime` values, but not dates.  Alas.